# Error on import statement in JavaScript/React Native code

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to incorporate a React component for radio buttons in my iOS app that's written in React Native, however I get an error when trying to import the component using the method that the author specified.

I first installed the component in the root directory of the app's XCode project/source code using the following statement:

```
npm i -S react-native-radio-buttons
```

Everything looked like it went through fine, so I incorporated the code for the component into the JS file for the screen that would use it, but I get an error on the very first line (which contains the import statement).

The import statement goes like this:

```
import { RadioButtons } from 'react-native-radio-buttons'
```

And the error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

As far as I can tell, that should be an acceptable way of doing things in ES6.  If anyone could tell me why this would happen, I'd be grateful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native-radio-buttons` author here,

I assumed everybody was using Babel with ES6 features enabled. I should add that to the README.

**Edit: instruction and example `.babelrc` added to `0.4.2`**

Please try add this `.babelrc` file to your project root, as the provided example does:

```
{
  "whitelist": [
    "es6.modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Added the .babelrc, and after I put "use babel" at the top of the files that have the import statements, it started to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a tool to translate from ES6? "import" is not going to work. Have you tried:

```
var RadioButtons = require('react-native-radio-buttons');
```

instead?

Comment: No, not using a tool.  According to the following page, the import statement should work in ES6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

I tried changing it to the code you suggested, but it then gives errors elsewhere in the imported component's code that use similar import syntax - so unfortunately that doesn't seem like it'll be a solution.

Comment: What I'm saying is 'import' *is* ES6 and must be translated into another syntax for React Native to be happy. Are the subsequent errors possibly getting you closer to a fix?

Comment: Furthermore, I just confirmed this syntax in my own test project produces the same error as you have reported.

Comment: Oh I see.  I changed all the import statements to the syntax you suggested, and now it's complaining about the export statements, which look like the following:

    export default RadioButtons;
    export { SegmentedControls };
    export { RadioButtons }

I was going to change them to something like module.exports = Item; but I'm not sure what to do with the "default" export line.

Comment: Try shoving the source through Babel directly first. That might help.

Comment: OK, I put the problematic files through babel, and it got through the compile phase - but then it crashes on the line where I actually try to use the RadioButtons component that I imported. 

The error is "Invariant Violation: Expected a component class, got [object Object]".  It seems like it's not actually importing the component properly. 

A suggested solution to this specific error is elsewhere on stackoverflow and says to put the require statement at the beginning of the function that uses it and not at the beginning of the file, but that didn't fix the error.

Comment: You might need to change this line to use the normal React.createClass(...) syntax (I've seen this issue before):  https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/react-native-radio-buttons/blob/master/lib/radio-buttons.js#L17

Comment: Hmm, that would be odd because it uses the same syntax as I do for my own classes and they work fine, but I went ahead an did that anyway.  It then gave an "Unexpected Token" error 8 lines later at the next function (componentWillMount).  I guess it didn't like that change.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for all your help xanadont.  Wasn't able to get it going yet, but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Sure. Sorry you couldn't get it going.